# Read optocoupler inputpullup pnp by MCU

Tags: opto-isolator, pnp

I have a switch and want to read digital input pull up state  from arduino.

[image]

how can the key open the pc 817 optocoupler and trigger the pnp gate to read inputpullup pin from digital arduino.

That make me crasy my new update work good on a digital input of esp32 but it do not work on a imput of mcp23017 i don't understand why .
any comment are welcom

Comment: You have used an NPN symbol for Q5 - please change it to PNP.  I think you need a pull-up resistor on Q5 base.

Comment: Q5 isn’t adding much value to your circuit. You can simplify it by connecting pin4 of the pc817 to 5V and pin3 to R4/digital input.  R3,5 and Q5 are removed.

Comment: Thank you for your advises i have made an error on my testing board about one resistor near the optocoupler witch  have make me a to high voltage drop.

Comment: the pnp is allready  implemented in the 16 channel board i have buy so i will not remove it.

Comment: I have 24 volt on switch side  and 5 volt on mcu side witch will enter in a mcp23017.

Comment: My question is it' necessary to put a schmith trigger before enter in mcp23017 to have a clean signal because on the board mcu esp32 i will have 4 mcp23017